# Blog posts not displaying

Tags: posts, troubleshooting

on my Wordpress site on the first page I always get my posts displaying however when I navigate to my 'Blog' page with my blog template attached to it I cant get my posts to display here.

I used a wordpress function to echo out the current page template on the first page and it is getting the index.php template. My blog page is getting the blog template. I have copied and pasted the code

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></p>

<?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?> 

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<h2>Woops...</h2>

<p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>

</div>
```

But i only get the form for posting comments. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong I would have thought it blog.php had the same code as index.php they would look identical..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "Settings" menu in the wordpress admin panel Select the "Reading" options and select your blog page for "Posts Page" from the dropdown beside it, see the screenshot here http://d.pr/i/h4nV

Hope it will help

Comment: Awesome man, thanks!! I had used this before to set the front page to static but didnt realise there was an option for your blogs post too. Thanks Again. Just one other question when I click on the blog post it says 'Comments are closed' and gives me and wont let me respond. Is there another option I have to change to allow this? I am logged in as admin..

Comment: You can turn on comments and other settings from the Settings->Discussion sections 

Also, for each of the posts you can turn on/off commenting by opening the post in edit mode, then click on "Screen" on the top right corner, then check the "Discussion" checkbox. After that, you will find a new metabox under the post content/excerpt area from where you can Allow commenting :)

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer which solves your problem as accepted answer. It encourage the person who answer your question in StackExchange.

Comment: When i click on screen options it doesnt do anything Hasin..

Comment: it should scroll down and show a list of options (make sure you are in the post in edit mode )

Comment: Yes sorry I was going to accept your answer was just away from the computer.

Comment: Yea I am in edit mode. I have tried creating a new post as well to test and it wont give me any more options either when I click on 'screen options' I have tried in Chrome and Safari..

Comment: that's kinda weird!

Comment: Tried it in Firefox and it worked fine.. strange one :P lol but cheers anyways man..